# Display text on bubble maps and dynamic re-scale for y-axis

Tags: javascript, python, json, charts, altair

I am currently trying to use Altair package in Python to plot charts, and I have two questions that I am unable to figure out:

1. Is there an easy way to display a text on each circle in the below map when using `mark_circle().encode()` method?
2. How to **dynamically** scale the vertical of a chart when two of them are placed on top of each other, so that the chart on the bottom has its x-axis labels **displayed** properly (see the color)?

**Sample Data** (market.json file)

```
[{"name":"X1, A1","type":"Small \/ City","lat":39.4,"lon":-76.3,"supply":1234,"rev":107.52},{"name":"X2, A2","type":"Small \/ City","lat":32.4,"lon":-99.5,"supply":1235.0,"rev":123},{"name":"X3, A3","type":"Mid City","lat":41,"lon":-81.2,"supply":7891,"rev":103.73},{"name":"X4, A4","type":"Rural \/Twin","lat":34.35,"lon":-87.3,"supply":6965.0,"rev":123.2},{"name":"X5, A5","type":"Rural \/Twin ","lat":31.23,"lon":-86.24,"supply":5617.2,"rev":123.87},{"name":"X6, A6","type":"Rural \/Twin","lat":61.27,"lon":-150.12,"supply":5182.0,"rev":128.3}]
```

**Sample Code for 1st Figure**

```
from vega_datasets import data

mkt = pd.read_json(market.json')
mkt_list = mkt['name'].unique().tolist()

# define selections
select_box = alt.binding_select(options=mkt_list, name='Make')
mkt_sel = alt.selection_single(fields=['name'], empty='none', bind=select_box,
                                    init={'name': 'X1, A1'})

regions = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.market.json, feature="states")
background = alt.Chart(regions).mark_geoshape(
    fill="#deebf7",
    stroke="white"
).project("albersUsa")

map = alt.Chart(mkt).mark_circle().encode(
    lat="lat:Q",
    lon="lon:Q",
    color=alt.Color('rev:Q', title='Rev',
                    scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues', reverse=True)),
    size=alt.Size('supply:Q', title='Supply'),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('name:N', title='Name'),
        alt.Tooltip('type:N', title='Type'),
        alt.Tooltip('rev:Q', format=".2f", title='Rev')
    ]
).add_selection(
    mkt_selector
).properties(
    width=200,
    height=100,
    title="Sample Map",
  )

)
country_map = alt.layer(background, map).resolve_legend(
        color="independent",
        size="independent"
        )
```

**Sample Output**

[image: Country Map]

[image]

Comment: You can place text with `mark_text()`. So in you example probaly something like `map + map.mark_text().encode(text='supply')`. For more help, could you please create  reproducible exampleusing sample data?

Comment: @joelostblom Thank you very much, I will try out your suggestion. I thought I already included the sample data and the code that uses to run the sample data? I am pretty sure it would generate the "bubble" graph on your end. You could not get that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line. Added an answer with an example (I had to change some code that wasn't working as pasted above). I don't understand your second question, try asking that separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mark_text()`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt


mkt = pd.read_json(
    StringIO("""[{"name":"X1, A1","type":"Small \/ City","lat":39.4,"lon":-76.3,"supply":1234,"rev":107.52},{"name":"X2, A2","type":"Small \/ City","lat":32.4,"lon":-99.5,"supply":1235.0,"rev":123},{"name":"X3, A3","type":"Mid City","lat":41,"lon":-81.2,"supply":7891,"rev":103.73},{"name":"X4, A4","type":"Rural \/Twin","lat":34.35,"lon":-87.3,"supply":6965.0,"rev":123.2},{"name":"X5, A5","type":"Rural \/Twin ","lat":31.23,"lon":-86.24,"supply":5617.2,"rev":123.87},{"name":"X6, A6","type":"Rural \/Twin","lat":61.27,"lon":-150.12,"supply":5182.0,"rev":128.3}]""")
)
mkt_list = mkt['name'].unique().tolist()

regions = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature="states")
background = alt.Chart(regions).mark_geoshape(
    fill="#deebf7",
    stroke="white"
).project("albersUsa")

mkt_map = alt.Chart(mkt).mark_circle().encode(
    latitude="lat:Q",
    longitude="lon:Q",
    color=alt.Color('rev:Q', title='Rev',
                    scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues', reverse=True)),
    size=alt.Size('supply:Q', title='Supply'),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('name:N', title='Name'),
        alt.Tooltip('type:N', title='Type'),
        alt.Tooltip('rev:Q', format=".2f", title='Rev')
    ]
).properties(
    title="Sample Map",
)

background + mkt_map + mkt_map.mark_text().encode(
    size=alt.Size(),
    text='supply:Q',
    color=alt.value('black')
)
```

[image]